# Cannot add team projects in VS2015 for new collections (TF250044)

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, tfs

On premise TFS2013 w/ SharePoint used with VS2013 and VS2015 which has for all intents and purposes been working fine for a long time.  But today I tried to create a new collection and have run into a brick wall.

The situation is that I am able to create new team projects on my previous collections, but not on new collections from either VS2013 or 2015.  I have a hard time knowing how to provide information for someone to help me.

I have compared all my permissions and security between the old collections and the new collections; although I could be missing a permission/group and not know it, but they seem the same.  The fact that I can create a new team project on, for instance, the DefaultCollection (which I previously wasn't using), and also another collection I created a year ago, but not be able to do this on a collection I create today is a real stumper for me.  That fact that I can do it on the older collections would seem to eliminate certain obvious problems.  Here is the error message:

[image]

I see one thing in the error message that catches my attention, but I don't know how to undertand what it might mean.  The error  mentions the site where permission is lacking at `...site/mse/mse`.  But in reality the only site that exists is `...site/mse`.  No projects have yet been created. The final part of the URL in the message refers to the team project being created, so it won't really exist until after the project is created.  If SharePoint is really trying to match permissions to a non-existent site, of course it won't work.  Now that could be a mistake in the error message, or some insight to a fundamental error I'm making but I don't understand.

Ideas?

**Added after solution found**: See the comment under the marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message this usually to be a permission issue. Give a try with the solution in below links:

- [Cannot create new TFS 2010 project with SharePoint: TF250044](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2efb31f8-10ed-400b-8e22-4368a24e7640/cannot-create-new-tfs-2010-project-with-sharepoint-tf250044?forum=tfsgeneral)
- [TFS 2012 - error TF218017 SharePoint site cannot be created](https://serverfault.com/questions/448321/tfs-2012-error-tf218017-sharepoint-site-cannot-be-created)
- https://dotblogs.com.tw/franma/2012/06/03/72583 (Just follow the pictures for the permission settings)

Comment: Obviously you were right, but thought I'd add my specific issue in case others make my mistake. I logged into TFS through RDC not noticing I logged in using a server account, not a domain account. TFS happily created a collection, but SharePoint wasn't so happy. The team site was, if this is a correct metaphor, 'orphaned'.  Not created w/ a domain acct messed up SharePoint permissions royally.  After logging in as a domain account, new collections worked as before.  I think the error message's user acct name gave a hint on that, I just didn't recognize it.